# I want to iterate over columns in python and get the column names & values at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that is about the class grades. Each column is the grade of each homework. The column names are: HW1, HW2, HW3... HW8.
I need to get the average value of each column, which means the average mean of each homework of the whole class. Also, I need to print the result.

The codes that I use are the following:

```
for column in dats:
    print(dats[column].mean())
```

I want to print the result like this:

```
HW1:50
HW2:40
...
HW8:90
```

I am struggling with the iteration of the column names.
Could you please help me with that?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as ps

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 4)), columns=['HW1', 'HW2', 'HW3', 'HW4'])
[print(f'{i}: {k}') for k, i in zip(df.mean(), df.mean().index)];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Because I have more than 10 columns to iterate, I want to find an easy way to iterate not type the column name.

Comment: you do not iterate over columns here., but generally just do `[c for c in df.columns]`

Answer (score 0):

The `mean` function takes a list as a parameter, try using

```
for column in dats:
    print(mean(dats[column]))
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried, but got an error like this:

`6 # write your codes here
      7 for column in dats:
----> 8     print(mean(dats[column]))

NameError: name 'mean' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer:

```
for column in dats:
    name = column
    print(name + ':' + str(dats[column].mean()))
```